# Autocomplete doesn't work on certain inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

jQuery UI autocomplete plugin not working

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#category').autocomplete({
        source : 'suggestion.do',
        width : 300,
        max : 10,
        delay : 100,
        cacheLength : 1,
        scroll : true,
        highlight : false
    });
});
```

Writing this works

> ["abcd","abc"]

This one does not work, unless it is provided directly (not loaded from an external file):

> [{label: "Choice1", value: "value1" },{ label: "Choice2", value: "value2" }]

Comment: "not working" Can you describe what isn't working? Maybe set up a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi can u elaborate. what i did is just wrote the data directly in an external file. I wrote the two cases. 1st one works. 2nd doesn't. However 2nd works if it is directly given in js.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi the contents of suggestion is the one given above in bold

Comment: @Sharlike by not working I mean the autocomplete suggestions doesn't load. can't arrange a jsfiddle cause the direct html jquery will work but doesn't work for the particular given input on loading from external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put the key values in quotes. It will be

```
[{"label": "Choice1", "value": "value1" },{ "label": "Choice2", "value": "value2" }]
```